# WPF,C# using VS2010

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I made Binding with CheckBox ,Lable, implemented BoolToVisibleOrHidden class, means when `checkBox1.IsChecked` Lable should be displayed, what I want to implement is in checkbox checked EventHandler, I want to implement with MessageBox. If `Messabox.Yes` then only Label should be displayed,

```
 <CheckBox Name="_checkBoxExpertMode" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DisplayChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
 <Lable  Name="_lableDisplay" Visibility="{Binding Path=DisplayChecked, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"
                                                          />

 System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult dialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Sure", "Some Title", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
              if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                _checkBoxExpertMode.IsChecked = true;
            }
           else if (dialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
           {
               _checkBoxExpertMode.IsChecked = false;
           }
```

But Label is displaying before Messagebox popup.

Help me, thanks in advance

Comment: can u write your code in better format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the binding on the checkbox and use the [Checkbox.Checked event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked.aspx).

```
<CheckBox Name="..." Checked="CheckBox_Checked"  />
```

In the event handler, display the message box and use a property to indicate if the label should be displayed :

```
public class MyWindow
{
    public bool ShouldLabelBeDisplayed { get; set; }

    public void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(...);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            ShouldLabelBeDisplayed = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ShouldLabelBeDisplayed = false;
        }
    }
```

Finally, bind the Visible property of your label to this property :

```
    <Label Name="..." Visibility="{Binding Path=ShouldLabelBeDisplayed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
```

It might not be exactly this but you get the idea.

Comment: thank you, its working, one more question , suppose if i have another lable in another UserControl2, if i gave these properties i got problem like displaying before MessageBox displays,

Answer (score 0):

tru to make a property of label to:

```
yourlabel.Visibility="Hidden".
```

Then when you want to show, you should make property:

```
yourlabel.Visibility="Visible".
```